# What's the order of construction of an extend-ing Moose object class?

Tags: perl, moose

I wrote a Moose object class which extends another Moose object class:

```
package MySubClass;
use Moose;
extends MySuperClass;
```

I have an attribute which I'd like to automatically build upon object instantiation:

```
has 'id' => (
    is       => 'ro',
    isa      => 'Str',
    builder  => '_build_id',
    init_arg => undef,
); 

sub _build_id {
 my $self = shift;
 # both ssn and bnn are attributes of MySuperClass
 return $self->ssn . $self->bnn;
}
```

This doesn't work unless I set `id` as lazy. Why?

How is the construction of `extend`ing objects done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote [Moose::Manual::Attributes on Laziness](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3a%3aManual%3a%3aAttributes#Laziness):

> First, if the default value for this
>   attribute depends on some other
>   attributes, then the attribute must be
>   lazy. During object construction,
>   defaults are not generated in a
>   predictable order, so you cannot count
>   on some other attribute being
>   populated when generating a default.